# I am trying to set up a spreadsheet that will send an email order to suppliers when stock gets low

Tags: javascript, email, google-sheets

I am trying to set up a spreadsheet that will send an email order to suppliers when stock gets low I cant figure out how to get it to loop through and compare each row in two columns and send an email if supply is below minimum

```
 function readCell() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("SHEET1");  
    var value = sheet.getRange("B5").getValue();
    var value1 = sheet.getRange("C5").getValue();
    if(value>value1) MailApp.sendEmail('BRIAn@ELLYSONTEC.COM', 'ORDER',     
    'TRANSFER BELT');
    };
```

Comment: please specify your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a small example that should get you started. I have also shared a spreadsheet sample you can copy.

```
//Col A is email. Col B is Part.
//Col C is Min Qty. Col D is Stock.
function readCellRevised() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); 
    var lr=sheet.getLastRow()
    var value = sheet.getRange(2,1,lr-1,4).getValues();
    value.sort()//sort value so email addresses are together
    var uem=keepUnique()//get unique email addresses
    for(m=0;m<uem.length;m++){ //for rach email address
       text="" //set text to blank for each new email
      for(i=0;i<value.length;i++){
        if(value[i][2]>value[i][3] && uem[m][0]==value[i][0]){
         var amt=value[i][2]-value[i][3] //how much to order
         var prod=value[i][1] //what to order
         var addr=value[i][0] //where to send
         var text =text+" I need to order "+ amt +" "+prod+"\n" //combine text with line breaks
      }}
   // Logger.log(text)// use to test messages
      MailApp.sendEmail(addr, 'ORDER', text); // send emails
     }}
function keepUnique(){//get unique email addresses
  var col = 0 ; // choose the column you want to use as data source (0 
  indexed, it works at array level)
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); 
  var lr=sheet.getLastRow()
  var data = sheet.getRange(2,1,lr-1,1).getValues();//get column A
  var newdata = new Array();
  for(nn in data){
    var duplicate = false;
    for(j in newdata){
      if(data[nn][col] == newdata[j][0]){
        duplicate = true;
      }}
    if(!duplicate){
      newdata.push([data[nn][col]]);
    }}
    return newdata
  }
```

The spreadsheet is:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Xj4QADpJORpxmbry9He0Rs4UhhFRQ-Q5j9fMC8Pnp58/edit?usp=sharing
```

Comment: thank you Ed that works really well I have set all up and was wondering if something could be added to put the amount ordered in the ordered column so I know how much we have on order? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16IRpka2kPbhPuZsTZGvl1Q2W20DSR4SO681VmVa_rPs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want. I can add what you ordered to Sheet1 and also add if email was sent and exclude that from future emails. Is that what you are after?

Comment: I attached the spreadsheet link in the last comment I added a column called ordered I would like it to be updated with how many were ordered which will bring the total up to being in a non order state to prevent accidental double ordering then when the product comes in I can move it from ordered to stock maualy. thank you

Comment: Try adding sheet.getRange(i+2, 7, 1, 1).setValue(amt) after var amt=value[i][2]-value[i][3] //how much to order

Comment: I had all kinds of trouble with that one I am still trying to learn some of the most basic things about google sheets and I really appreciate your help. I think I am going to do some more reading and tinkering and see what I can learn on my own for now. do you have a way I can send you a few bucks for a coffee or whatever for your help.

Comment: Just accept my answer by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer. Do you want me to make that change on the spreadsheet you shared with me?

Comment: This should work. I made a change to the email format also. Let me know if you have problems. Note I had to change the function names in the two gs files to be unique.https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QlyK74HGI48qR4HrgN_6iqp59wPPco9AwzOuCsZvjaI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Ed could you please post the new scripts here.

Comment: There is a lot of script. Just go to file, Copy,  make a copy and you can copy the script from the script editor.

Comment: the vivo script is sending a lot of emails with no data on top of the ones with data and the script for neura does not seem to be functioning.

Comment: I fixed the blank email problem. Note that sending the email is commented out. Remove the '//' to send. You can see what should be sent by going to the View option in the script editor and selecting Logs. neura doesn't have anything to order. This conversation is getting long. Why don't you email me at ednelson@sbcglobal.net with further questions.